# Jquery ajax setTimeout after form succes not redirecting?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

I tried questions showing up before asking a question didnt have chance to make it work.
it works fine when I add it to mail send success alert, But I dont want to add script in php part.

> I am trying to redirect contact page to an another page after form
>   success and delay a few seconds.

Here is my Jquery ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ContactForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url:"modules/contact.inc.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:formValues,
        dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
                if(data.error === 'ok'){
                    $('#result').html(data.error);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location = 'index.php';
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    $('#result').html(data.error);
                    $('#ContactForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried the folowing `setTimeout();` in success function but didnt work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace("index.php");
},1000);
```

Then I tried : `window.location.replace("index.php");` without setTimeout function didnt work too.

```
window.location.href
window.location.hostname
window.location
```

This one works for modal in another page

```
setTimeout(function() {
window.location.reload();
}, 3000);
```

These are my tries didnt have a chance, Thanks for any advice and help.

EDIT: Here is php part for data.error contain:

```
$error     = "";

    // Validate user name
    if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
        $error .= "<p class='error'>İsim girmediniz.</p>";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    }   

    // Validate email address
    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
        $error .= "<p class='error'>E-Posta girmediniz.</p>";     
    } else{
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error .= "<p class='error'>E-Posta doğru formatta değil.</p>";
        }
    }   

    // Validate user subject
    if(empty($_POST["subject"])){
        $error .= "<p class='error'>Konu girmediniz.</p>";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }

        // Validate user message
    if(empty($_POST["message"])){
        $error .= "<p class='error'>Mesaj girmediniz.</p>";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    // Validate user departman
    if(empty($_POST["departmant"])){
        $error .= "<p class='error'>departman Seçin.</p>";
    } else {
        $departman = test_input($_POST["departmant"]);
    }
    if($error === ''){
        require "../PHPMailer/mailer.php";
        $mail = new mailSend();
        $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $name = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
        $departman = test_input($_POST["departmant"]);
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        $error = $mail->sendMail($email,$name,$subject,$departman,$message); 
    }else{
        $error .= "<p class='error'>Formda bir hata oluştu.</p>";
    }
$data = array(
 'error'  => $error
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

> EDIT : Got it work thanks for answers,

Displaying error causing the problem, `$('#result').html(data.error);` I changed it to text message instead of success message from php:

```
$('#result').html('Form successfuly');
 $('#ContactForm')[0].reset();
 setTimeout(function() {
   window.location = 'index.php';
 }, 1000);
```

it works fine.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you inspected the AJAX request in the network log and does it complete successfully? Have you put any alerts/`console.log()`s to step through your code and see where it's reaching? Etc.

Comment: I put alert('message') its success in console and form is success too.

Comment: `data.error` is a strange property name to signify success. What *precisely* does `data.error` contain?

Comment: I will edit question and add php part so you can see how data.error contains 2 second please, it could be data.Msg or something else too, do you think it will change or cause something ?

Comment: Are you sure that  `$mail->sendMail($email,$name,$subject,$departman,$message)` returns `ok`?

Comment: lol. yes it does, its caling phpmailer function  and yes it does, and when I include window.location.replace("index.php"); in mail_send success alert it works fine redirecting page but I wanted to add in jquery code not in php part.

Comment: Are you already on "index.php"?

Comment: No, am in contact page, I probably need to add it somewhere else instead of adding in success function in ajax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) requires two parameters. As written, it will look for the string "index.php" and replace it with nothing. Try adding a regex to match everything and replace with your new URL.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace( /.*/, "index.php");
},1000);
```

Use the full URL (i.e. `https://yourdomain.com/index.php`) or write a better regex. For instance, if your domain ends with **.com**, you could do something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace( /\.com\/.*/, ".com/index.php");
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, dont work in ajaq code same as in question :( looks like I am gonna keep it in php alert form success.

Comment: @Dilek Go here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax
and add this to the success function:

setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
      },1000);

You'll see it works there. Perhaps you can try to rewrite your ajax call.