# Ajax json response returning undefined value

Tags: php, jquery

Im new to kinda new to coding and im having a issue with my ajax json response. The response works fine, but when im trying to alert out my json object in the success field it gives me an undefined value.

Here  is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            url:"ajaxHandlers/createUser.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{newUser:newUser, createPassword: createPassword, createEmail:createEmail},
            success:function(data)
            {    

              alert(data);
            }
          });
```

Here is the php file im calling createUser.php

```
<?php

$newUser = $_POST['newUser'];
$createPassword = $_POST['createPassword'];
$createEmail = $_POST['createEmail'];

$array = [
    "user" => $newUser
];
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

And when i do an alert on the data im getting the following response

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customcss/mystyle.css">
    <title>Todo V2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  {"error":"test"}
```

Also when i look in networks i have the following response

```
{"error":"test"}
```

And when i try to alert out the object like this

```
data.error
```

I get undefined.

What is it im doing wrong?

Thankfull for any help
Yours / Julie

Comment: show your php part

Comment: Maybe try removing the quotes from “error”

Comment: From my array in php?

Comment: Use this in html form and see if still empty  `<div id="result"></div>` and add this in ajax success function `$('#result').html(data.error);` next to alert or change with alert

Comment: I tried it, and i get nothing in the result div....

Comment: I dont see error alert in your php can you add php part where you set errors Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting

Comment: in the result div and i do this $('#result').html(data); i get the following in the result div {"error":"test"}

Comment: Then you have to change error to `data` in php part see the link I gave all your answer is in that link, its because your are not setting alerts in php part and, need to change `$array = [
    "user" => $newUser
];
echo json_encode($array);
?>` To `$array = [
    "data" => $data
];
echo json_encode($array);
?>`

Comment: I still get undefined ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting

Comment: Is this all your php code?  You appear to be getting html code before the ajax response.  The ajax response should be first and should be preceded with `header(‘Content-Type: application/json’);`

Answer (score 0):

Added `dataType: "json"` to the AJAX request to specify that you expect JSON in the response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxHandlers/createUser.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        newUser: newUser,
        createPassword: createPassword,
        createEmail: createEmail
    },
    dataType: "json",  // Specify the expected data type
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));  // Use JSON.stringify to display the JSON object
    }
});
```

Use `JSON.stringify` to display the JSON object