# Ajax email Availability check with php not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ajaxform

I want to check email availability but it's not working. and also I am new to javascript and ajax please help me.

his is my code
email input with span to show output(for now there is no output)

```
<input class="input--style-4" id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
<span id="user-availability-status"></span>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').blur(function() {
      var email = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'includes\emailAvailability.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          email_val: email
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data != 0) {
            $('#user-availability-status').html('<span>Username blah not available</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
          } else {
            $('#user-availability-status').html('<span>Username blah Available</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", false);
          }
        }
      })
    });
  });
</script>
```

PHP file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["email_val"])) {
    include("DbConn.php");
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email_val"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

Comment: how do you get `if (data != 0) {` from php for Username blah ?

Comment: what i didn't get it :)

Comment: 1. you are wide open to sql injection, 2. you need to set errors array in php part and encode it with json then display in form. First check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1 AND than check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string ? sql injection possible?????

Comment: This is sql injection `'" . $email . "'";`

Comment: aaa okay thanks :)

Comment: but any way ajax not still working

Comment: hi, inspect element in Chrome, go to Network tab. when you type something you will see new request. check the response text of emailAvailability.php

Comment: is it 0 or 1? maybe there's an error

Comment: 0 because when there is no email it will return 0 so,then out put should be Username blah Available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check link I refered in comment its your complete answer.

here is a Simple example with your code.

```
include("DbConn.php");
    // Set alerts as array 
$error     = "";

    // I should just trrim and let you check if email is empty .lol 
if (empty($_POST["email_val"])) {
    $error .= "<p class='error'>Fill email value.</p>";

    //Check if this is a real email 
} elseif(!filter_var($_POST["email_val"],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error .= "<p class='error'>Wrong email type.</p>";
}else{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email_val"]);

    //You should use prepare statement $email, Shame on you .lol    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '{$email}'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $error .= "ok";
}
$data = array(
 'error'  => $error
);
```

This Jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url:"includes\emailAvailability.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:formValues,
        dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
                if(data.error === 'ok'){
                    $('#result').html(data.error);
                } else {
                    $('#result').html(data.error);
                    $('#myform')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And Html :

```
<form id="myform">
  <input class="input--style-4" id="email" type="email" name="email_val">
  <span id="result"></span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use type:"POST" instead of method:"POST" I think work thanks

Comment: I think 'mailAvailability.php' not get post value. reason is there is used method not is type

Comment: what is return in inspect to console or network tab , please capture image

Comment: i am new to web dev so dont know what is is :)

Comment: Ok, you can use right click then go to the last link to "inspect" element after seeing to console and network tab