# Submitting Form using jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to submit my form using jQuery ajax, but my data isn't posting to PHP it returns empty array nothing in `$_POST` array.

This is my code - here is my form:

```
<form action = "/webdevelopmentpakistan/send_mail.php" method = "post" class = "myForm"   >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" id="fname" type="text" required name= "full_name" placeholder="Full Name" 
                             />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" required name = "phone" placeholder="+92" id="phone" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" required name = "email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn popup" type="submit"    name = "submit" value="CONTACT OUR CONSULTANT"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

its an ajax part:

```
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();


    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $('.myForm').serialize() ,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function (data) { // here I'm adding data as a parameter which stores the response

                    console.log(data); // instead of alert I'm changing this to console.log which logs all the response in console.
            },
             error:function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError, data)
             {
                 console.log("Error: " + thrownError);
                 console.log("Error: " + textStatus);


             }
                   });



    // var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    // popup.classList.toggle("show");
    console.log(form_data);

});
```

PHP CODE using at other page:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
        echo json_encode($_POST);
    }
```

and this is my serialize array which I am getting on submission of form but it isn't getting passed to php

```
full_name=talha&phone=012345678&email=admin%40gmail.com
```

Comment: Check what the actual request looks like in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: no its still same data is fetched through serialization but its isnt getting post to php .

Comment: when i fetch using $_POST['full_name'] is says undefined index

Comment: No argument was passed in success function - `function(data)`

Comment: nothing changed data still not passing.. 

Notice: Undefined index: full_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdevelopmentpakistan\web-development-in-pakistan.php on line 6

Comment: can you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: In ajax request, datatype should be as "dataType" (T caps).

Comment: array(0) { } this shows

Comment: array(3) {
  ["full_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["phone"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: @V_Dev  change  to dataType still same results

Comment: Try: `<form action="./web-development-in-pakistan.php" ....`

Comment: See this answer for complete example of ajax `POST` method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594761/12232340 if you want to fetch data then you need to change `POST` to `GET` if you are using ajax post method, you cant use `action` in form tags like this `<form action = "/web-development-in-pakistan.php" method = "post" class = "myForm"  target="_self">` it should be like : `<form method = "post" class = "myForm"  target="_self">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow, here are the changes, hope it will works

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: $('.myForm').serialize() ,
    dataType : 'json', // changing data type to json
    success: function (data) { // here I'm adding data as a parameter which stores the response
        console.log(data); // instead of alert I'm changing this to console.log which logs all the response in console.
    }
});
```

> in php

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

this should print array of post parameters in your console, however you will get an array in php.

Comment: actually i am posting data to the same page in which the form is and after posting data i am showing a popup modal in which i am using recaptcha nd also i am storing posted data in variables so i can post them again after verifying recaptcha

Comment: success: function (data) {
        console.log(data); 
    }
success function is not working json gves error reponse ..

Comment: and what is the error in console can you please check?

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2

this is the error i am getting

Comment: okay as per your description, the php code for ajax call is also on the same page right?

Comment: okay can you please move your php code to separate page, where only the response should be return because when you r calling the api also html content might be returned so it gives you error, just change the php page and form action too.

Comment: ok now it isn't giving me error but the array still empty no data getting post

{full_name: "", phone: "", email: ""}
full_name: ""
phone: ""
email: ""
__proto__: Object

Comment: serialized array is generating but not getting post further 
here is my serialized array
full_name=talha&phone=03204789963&email=admin%40gmail.com

do i have to covert it to some other format ??

Comment: no its just fine, you can try after removing `dataType`, and, I am really having trouble to debug your code can you please update your latest code to your question so it will be more clear

Comment: i have solved it .. thanks alot for your time and help 
i just change serialized array into JSON object using JSON.stringify($(this).serialize())
and this done the job , thanks again for helping through this .

Comment: 1 last thing how can i used this JSON object to store data in variable ?

Comment: you will get the object array on php so it will working same as before like $_POST['first_name'].

Answer (score 0):

The form action needs to be either absolute url i.e. `https://somewebsite.com` or a relative url on you site so ideally it should be `/some-url.php`. Read about [form action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute) here

So your form opening tag should be,

```
<form action = "/web-development-in-pakistan.php" method = "post" class = "myForm"  target="_self">
```

So in your javascript code when you do

```
var url = $(this).attr("action");
```

I also believe that in your ajax call, the `type` needs to be `method`, so,

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  .....
 })
```