# My contact form does not work, submit button is not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a Bootstrap theme for my portfolio website. As far as I know, I changed all the parameters in the default php- and js-files in order for my contact form to work. I also made sure I have the correct settings in my server. However, when I press the submit button, it does not send anything. I'm also not receiving any sort of error message. 
Any idea where I went wrong/how to fix this issue?

In Javascript:

```
    $(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); 
      $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          phone: phone,
          email: email,
          message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>')
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); 
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

The PHP-file associated with it(I marked out my email):

```
    <?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));


$to = '*****@******.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@********.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

And the HTML-snippet:

```
      <!-- Contact -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Feel free to contact me!</h2>
          <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">How can I help you?</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                  <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: have you checked your browser console?

Comment: Is this correct path to file ? ././mail/contact_me.php and did you include jquery in your page ?

Comment: Maybe you need just `/mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the AJAX request going through properly? What about checking your PHP script for errors then - can all needed data be read?

Comment: See here How to post data via ajax and how to get response back from php https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340

Comment: Check the return value of `mail` for errors.

Comment: When running this page in Chrome, what do you see in the network tab of the Developer Tools when you submit the form? You should see the ajax request being made. Maybe put a console.log in the submitError function to see if anything is calling that instead of success too.