# How can I call a click event from another file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i need to call a click event from another file...

On my index.php I have a 'select' to choose a name, once I did, I call by Ajax a form by the name I choosed before, this form is on espacio.php, once I complete the form I must have to click a button to save the info, when I click this button the info are passed by Ajax to espacio2.php and there is here where I show a success or a failure message.

This message shows on my index.php and this is good, but I want to hide it after a few seconds.

How can I call the click event from espacio.php?

This is a code that works only if a click is pressed on the same page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".botoncete").click(function(){
        $(".prueba").fadeIn();
        Esconder();
    });

    function Esconder(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".prueba").fadeOut();
        },2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're sending the data by AJAX, you stay on the same page, so what's the problem?

Comment: I am on the same page but only visually, because on the back I'm sending the data from index.php to espacio.php and then to espacio2.php

Comment: It doesn't matter where you send the data. How are you loading `espacio2.php`? Show the AJAX code.

Comment: When you load a new page, all the old JS stops running. You'll need JS in the new page that fades out the message.

Comment: how do you get response ? by this Esconder(); ? if yes put it in setTimeout it will remove after 2 seconds you set in function

Comment: @Dilek 
The thing is that Esconder() is triggered after a click, and I don't have a button on the same page where my message is shown.

Comment: how do you get response back and show on page ? you should have a div in html and $('#result').html(data); to show response on index. see ajax in my question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340

Comment: Yes I have, on index.php there is a <div id="myDiv3"></div>, here it is where I send the success or the failure message.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved the problem, thanks to @Barmar, and as he said: "If you're sending the data by AJAX, you stay on the same page".

I really don't know what was I thinking...