# PHP Form same page Submission message

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm new to PHP and using the following code (which is working) but the page gets changed to another page, the website has different forms and I want the success message to appear on the form or any alert box format that doesn't effect the existing page. I need help with easy steps considering my beginning level.

**MY HTML CODE:**

```
<form action="order-mail.php" method="post" class="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input placeholder="Full Name *"  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" required>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input placeholder="Email Address *"  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input placeholder="Phone No. *"  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <textarea  name="comments" placeholder="To help us understand better, enter a brief description about your project."></textarea>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**MY PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
          $email_to = "email@mydomain.com";
          $email_subject = "xyz Form Submissions";

          function died($error) {
                // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
          }

            // validation expected data exists
          if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
        }

            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
            $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
            $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

            $error_message = "";
            $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

            if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
              $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
            }

            $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

            if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
              $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
            }

            if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
              $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
            }

            if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
              died($error_message);
            }

            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

            function clean_string($string) {
              $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
              return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
            }

            $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

        // create email headers
            $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

            ?>
            <!-- include your own success html here -->

            Thank you for the Submission

            <?php
          }
?>
```

Comment: 1. Create a variable to hold errors. 2. Put the PHP code above HTML, it would not be processed until there's something in $_POST. 3. Echo the error variable (should be empty at first. 4. In PHP validate every field, adding message to error variable if any. 5. If error variable is empty, send the email, echo success message and include a meta tag to redirect to another page.

Comment: See this question for getting response from ajax : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340 if you want touse ajax, Your codes in same page so, just echo out error message or see this tutorials and check how they show errors in form : https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Comment: can get this at all.. since I have mentioned I am too new and doing all this for learning perspective .... help me by posting it comparing my code if possible.

Comment: You have a few options: 1) use ajax to submit the form. This way php script responds with a json message that contains an error message or signals success (and javascript on the page redirects to the next page). 2) php script (which should always be before you output html) simply ignores trying to send email if `$error_message` is set, (don’t make the script die; just fall through to the html) and in your html show the error message if it is set. Option 1 is more professional and far better for users, but option 2 is much easier for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with a standard logic flow:

```
<?php

// deal with user input, if it exists 
if( $_POST['email']) {

    $error_message = '';
    // validate input, build $error_message if errors 

    // if no error message, send email 
    if( !$error_message ) {

        // send email...

        // redirect to next page
        header('Location: /path/to/next/page');
        die;
    }

}

// done with php logic; show view
?>
<html>
    <head>
    ... snip ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ... snip ...
    <?php if( isset( $error_message )): ?>
         <div><?= $error_message ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    ... the rest of your page ...
```

What have accomplished here:

- Separated logic from presentation. This is a procedural imitation of MVC: first deal with user input, then do all logic to display the page, and last of all display the output. Note that you should almost *never* need to use a `print` or `echo` command.
- The “controller“ part, since it precedes any output, is free to use `header()` commands, and thus can redirect or send output in any format (i.e., json encoded). This also allows usage of patterns such as PRG (Post-Redirect-Get). Every usage of POST should either be an ajax response or followed by a redirect. Note that a successful submission will result in a smooth transition to the next page.

As shown, however, there are a couple of problems to overcome if the fields don’t validate: all the inputs will be cleared because the page refreshed, and the back button will ask to resubmit the page if you try to go back.

Without using ajax, there’s not much you can do for the latter other than redirect back to the same page by passing user input as GET, or use SESSION to hold user input. Redirecting is the right thing to do, but for this example I’ll keep it simple.

Since failing validation causes script execution to “fall through” to the html, we can use POST variables, if present, to supply the value attribute of the inputs:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input placeholder="Full Name *"  
                   type="text" 
                   name="first_name" 
                   value="<?= $_POST['first_name'] ?? '' ?>" 
                   maxlength="50" 
                   size="30" 
                   required
                   >
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> Note: seeing POST variables referenced in the view (html) should be considered a sign that it could be done better!

This will get you the error messages and also prefill your form.