# I am able to inspect the hidden type variable but I am getting error of sending the input type hidden variable of HTML form to PHP file via JS

Tags: javascript, php

**Solution:**

```
This below not worked

        // var user_id = $('#attach-old-campaign-form').find('[name="userid"]').val();

        // var added_on = $('#attach-old-campaign-form').find('[name="addedon"]').val();

This below worked

        var lead_id = $('#attach-old-campaign-form-leadid').val();
        var user_id = $('#attach-old-campaign-form-userid').val();
        var added_on = $('#attach-old-campaign-form-addedon').val();
```

**Question:**

I am able to echo a PHP variable and also can see my variable assigned to `input type hidden variables` but when i send the HTML form with hidden type NO variable is received at JS function and also it raise error in my PHP server file `attach_old_campaign.php`.

PIC

[image]

[image]

So I have three files `index.html`, `attach_old_campaign.js` and `attach_old_campaign.php`.

I have below part of code of `index.html`:

```
<?php

                    $user_id = $_SESSION['User_Id'];
                    $lead_id = $_GET['lead_id'];

                    echo "User id: ".$user_id;
                    echo "Lead_Id: ".$lead_id;

                    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
                    {

                    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
                    }   

                    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

                    ?>

                   <input type="hidden" name="leadid" value="<?php echo $_GET['lead_id'] ?>" >
                   <input type="hidden" name="userid" value= "<?php echo $_SESSION['User_Id'] ?>" >                    
                   <input type="hidden" name="addedon" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>" >
```

I am getting error at above input type hidden.

Also i am not able to console the output at my JS code file `attach_old_campaign.js`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 1000;

    $('[name="attach_old_campaign_submit"]').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var lead_id = $('#attach-old-campaign-form').find('[name="leadid"]').val();

        var campaign_arr = [];

        // Initializing array with Checkbox checked values
        $("input[name='checkedcampaign_arr']:checked").each(function(){
            campaign_arr.push(this.value);
        });

        var user_id = $('#attach-old-campaign-form').find('[name="userid"]').val();

        var added_on = $('#attach-old-campaign-form').find('[name="addedon"]').val();

        console.log(lead_id)
        console.log(user_id)
        console.log(added_on)
        console.log(campaign_arr)

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "./server/attach_old_campaign.php",
            data: {
                "lead_id": lead_id,
                "campaign_arr": campaign_arr,
                "user_id": user_id,
                "added_on": added_on
            }           

        });

    });

});
```

My PHP server file `attach_old_campaign.php`

```
<?php

// send a JSON encoded array to client

include('../../server/connection.php');

/* check connection */
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {


    $leadid = $_POST['lead_id'];
    $campaign_arr = $_POST['campaign_arr'];
    $userid = $_POST['user_id'];
    $addedon = $_POST['added_on'];

    foreach ($campaign_arr as $campaign_id) {


            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_mapping_lead_and_campaign` (`Map_Lead_Id`, `Map_Campaign_Id`, `MappingAddedBy`, `MappingAddedOn`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");

            $stmt->bind_param( "ssss", $leadid, $campaign_id, $userid, $addedon ); 

            if($stmt->execute()){

                echo "<span style='color:green;'>
                 Campaign information mapped to Lead successfully</span>";

            }else{

                echo "<span style='color:red;'> Campaign information NOT mapped to Lead..
                 </span><p></p>";

                printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);

            }    

    }

}else{

    echo "Error: %s".$conn->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't why this is happening

Comment: so why this is happening if i am echoing the variable then why i am not able to send it

Comment: Impossible for us to tell, with the rather chaotic and incomplete info you have given so far. Have you first of all checked the HTML output your PHP part creates, to verify that the form is correct?

Comment: yes this sending of hidden type is working for other files, want to see complete file

Comment: Just use ajax serialize method and get response from php, to see the result if values passing to php, echo  out php and see the result, simple and easy. Here is example ajax : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874137/12232340 and change php variables in inputs like this `<?php echo $_GET['lead_id']; ?>` Last point use POST method instead of GET

Comment: @mickmackusa please remove the duplicate tag this error need to removed, you have power to tag but that does not mean to press down the low power people

Comment: @Dilek, I have updated my post please help me out

Comment: @04FS, please remove duplicate tag there is no question similar to my problem in SO

Comment: @Dilek iu am using `GET` because i have value in my URL as `http://localhost/CRM/lead/index.html?lead_id=17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foos" name="any" value="bar" />
<script>
    $('input[name=any]').val();
</script>
```

Comment: `You can Use like that` is not an explanation.

Comment: but i want to use PHP variable

Comment: @mickmackusa please remove the duplicate tag this error need to removed, you have power to tag but that does not mean to press down the low power people

Comment: @Jayshri Ghoniya please see in this

Comment: I have not closed your question as a punishment, the duplicate link is provided to give you solutions and educational guidance.  This answer is low value and does not demonstrate how to generate a javascript variable.  The "solution" in your question does not resemble any of the mark up that you have provided.  This question is Unclear and will be very unlikely to help future researchers -- especially compared to the other page that is referenced.

Comment: This is a code-only answer that does not show a complete solution nor appreciates your provide html elements -- I am not sure why anyone would UV it or acept it.

Comment: @mickmackusa, don't worry just thanks

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how/why your code addresses it. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.