# Send POST request from an external site to Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I want a way to send POST from a **PHP site** to another one built with **Laravel (the second one)** to return a **JSON** value!

The PHP site (I use jQuery to send this POST):

```
$('#get_link_form').on('submit', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?= $d; ?>/link/go/blog",
            method:"POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType:'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data.msg != "") {
                   $('#sell_house_submit').html(data.msg);
                } else {
                   $('#sell_house_submit').removeAttr('disabled').attr('href', data.link).html("Get Link!");
                }
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

and the second site built with LARAVEL:

```
public function countlink_blog(Request $request) {

        $link_id = $request->link_id;
        $link = Link::where('link_id', $link_id)->get()->first();
        if ($link) {
            $count = new CountController();
        return response()->json(['link' => $link->redirect, 'msg' => '']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['link' => '', 'msg' => 'Your Link Is Invalid!']);
        }
}
```

Strange that I have prepared everything, and the POST is sent successfully, but I cannot receive any result? I don't understand why? knowing that **I removed CSRF from this ROUTE!**

Any way to do this in Laravel?

Comment: See here yu need to parse errors from php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting

Comment: try Postman app to check if your Laravel responses on the request

Comment: No errors, but if I put a TEXT like **echo "Hi";**, I can see the response but if I use **response()->json([]);** the response here is empty! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move route to api.php in Laravel and set your request header Accept: "application/json"

```
$.ajax({     
      headers: {          
        Accept: "application/json"
      }     
      data: "data",    
      success : function(response) {  
        // ...
      }
    });
```