# Delete a table row with dynamic id that comes from DB using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table that it's content is comes from database.When I click on the delete button I want to delete that row with Ajax. Actually right now it's working but with a bug and that is all of the rows get deleted when I click on the button and then if I refresh , the row that I was deleted is gone and other rows are shown.But as I said it needs a refresh.Any solution would be appreciated .

```js
$('.dashboard-subscribe-form').submit(() => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const currentHiddBtn = $('.dash-subscribe-form-btn');
  console.log(currentHiddBtn.closest('tr'));

  const userCaution = confirm('Want to delete this quote?');
  if (userCaution) { //If admin insists to delete the row
    const deleteId = $('.dash-subscribe-form-btn').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete-subscribe.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        deleteId: deleteId
      }, 
      success: (data) => {
        if (data.code === '200') {
          console.log('It works!');
          currentHiddBtn.closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
          currentHiddBtn.closest('tr').fadeOut(1200, () => {

          });

        } else if (data.code === '404') {
          alert('An error occurred!Please try again.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <?php
       $count = 1;
       $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM `kq0b3_subscribe`";
       $sqlCommandPrepare = $pdoObject->prepare($sqlCommand);
       $sqlCommandPrepare->execute();
       while ($result = $sqlCommandPrepare->fetch()) {
   ?>
   <tr id="row-<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">
      <td class="dashboard-records">
        <?php echo $count; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="dashboard-records">
        <?php echo $result['email']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post" class="dashboard-subscribe-form">
          <input id="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" type="hidden" class="dash-subscribe-form-btn" name="hidden-del" value='<?php echo $result[' id ']; ?>'/>
          <button type="submit" name="sub-del-btn" class="btn btn-danger del" value='<?php echo $result[' id ']; ?>'> Delete
           </button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     $count++;
       }
     ?>
</tbody>
```

delete-subscribe.php:

```php
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$delete_row = $_POST['deleteId'];


if($delete_row){
    $sqlCommand = "DELETE FROM `kq0b3_subscribe` WHERE `id` = ?";
    $sqlCommandPrepare = $pdoObject->prepare($sqlCommand);
    $result = $sqlCommandPrepare->execute([

        $delete_row

    ]);

    /*The json_encode() must be after all of our calculation codes and DB query codes and...(It must be the
       last line of code) */
    echo json_encode(['code' => '200'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512);
}
else {
    echo json_encode(['code' => '404'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512);
}
```

---

UPDATE2: now I'm using :

```
 $('#row-' + deleteId).css('background', 'tomato');
                    $('#row-' + deleteId).fadeOut(1200, () => {

                    });
```

but the new problem is : it doesn't matter which button I click, the forst row is deleted (when any button is clicked , in the console , the id of the first row-button is printed , not the actual id that I was clicked. ).How can I fix this one?

Comment: I think it's because the `delete-subscribe.php` file doesn't exist

Comment: Where are you running a delete?

Comment: @MisterJojo No I have created it

Comment: @user3783243 I delete the row from DB in delete-subscribe.php and it works correctly . The only bug is in my jquery but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: add codes delete-subscribe.php in question and what do you mean by *bug and that is all of the rows get deleted* ? and u can use `header('location: yourpage.php'); exit();` to refresh page. or 
                    `setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location = 'index.php';
                    }, 1000);` in ajax success function see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340

Comment: In your ajax success callback, why not just do: `$('#row-' + deleteId).css('background', 'tomato').fadeOut(1200);` instead of searching for the element using `closest()`? The `tr` you want to remove has an ID so just use that.

Comment: @Dlk Thank you , I edited my question and also look for that link.

Comment: add this `window.location.reload();` under this `if (data.code === '200') {` in ajax. there are more solutions in that answer I linked.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wow!You saved me. Now instead of all of the rows in my table , just one row is deleted.But now the row that is deleted is always the first row , no matter which button I deleted.

Comment: @Dlk I did what you said . `The window.location.reload();` and it just makes the delete animation (`.fadeout`) a little faster. NOW , The problem I have is : it doesn't matter which button (that has a specific id) I click, the first row is deleted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue, in this case, is using CSS classes as a selector and it seems to be selecting the first instance no matter which item you are clicking.

The code causing this is:

```js
const deleteId = $('.dash-subscribe-form-btn').attr('value');
```

You want to be getting the target input from the `event` object passed from your `.submit()`.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awnomcjd/) with an example that could be adapted to your code but here is a quick preview of jQuery part.

```js
$('.dashboard-subscribe-form').submit((event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.target.elements[0]["value"])
  $('#result-from-click').html("Input Value: " + event.target.elements[0]["value"])
})
```

It is selecting the first element within the elements array which is the input. If you want the button you can use `event.target.elements[1]`

You could then also use the value returned to remove the `<tr>` with the same  id instead of finding the nearest. This could be done in the `success` part of your `ajax` call without doing a refresh.