# Why will my html/css/php form only send me an email when the email address is valid? I want an email regardless

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is the code for my contact page. For some reason, it only sends me an email when the email entered by the user is valid, i have tested it with other entries and emails don't appear to send. I want to know whenever someone tries to contact me, regardless of whether their contact information is valid. Is there something I need to change in my code?

```
<?php
    if($_POST["message"]){
        $recipient="foo@example.com";
        $subject="Customer Inquiry";
        $sender=$_POST["sender"];
        $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
        $senderPhone=$_POST["senderPhone"];
        $message=$_POST["message"];

        $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n Phone: $senderPhone\n\n$message";

        mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
    }
?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang = "en">

<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <title>User Based Web Design</title>
    <!--title displayed in the tab, search-able title of the page-->

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Reset.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Contact Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Navigation Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Footer Styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header> <!--start visible header section-->
        <h1>Jane Doe</h1>
        <h2>User Based Web Design</h2>
    </header> <!--end visible header section-->

    <div class="navbar">
        <?php include 'nav.html';?>
    </div>

    <article class ="main_contact">
    <!--Start article section. -->

        <h1>Contact Questionnaire</h1>

        <div class = "intro_text">
            <p>Please use the Contact Questionnaire below if you need to reach me for any reason.</p>

            <p>I take your privacy very seriously. I will never share any of your 
            information with anyone outside legal requirements. You will never be spammed or marketed
            to by any of my partners.</p>

        </div>

        <div class = "contact_form">

            <form name="form4" action="Contact Us.php" method="post">

                <input type = "hidden" name ="recipient" value ="1">
                <input type = "hidden" name ="subject" value ="Contact Survey">
                <input type = "hidden" name ="print_blank_fields" value ="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="_pid" value="154040">
                <input type="hidden" name="_fid" value="A7QPIZEA">

                <table  class ="contact_table">
                    <tbody>

                        <!--Row 1-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Name:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="sender" id="name" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box required" title="Please type your name." required></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 2-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Email:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderEmail" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box"></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 3-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Phone:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderPhone" type="text" id="textfield2" maxlength="30"class ="input_text_box"></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 5-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 6-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">Preferred Method of <br />Contact:</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Preferred Contact" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_0"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2" width = "30%">Phone</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 8-->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Preferred Contact" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Email</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 11-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="1">Would you like a response?</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Yes</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_3"></td>
                                <td>No</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 19-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">What would you like<br />to talk to me about?</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Existing Customer Inquiry</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4"></td>
                                <td>New Customer Inquiry</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 25-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Message Text: </td>
                                <td colspan = "6" style="text-align: left">
                                    <textarea rows = "4" name="message" maxlength="800" id="Comments" class ="input_text_box" required></textarea></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 26-->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" style = "float:left"></td>
                                <td colspan = "5">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" style = "float:right"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form> 
        </div>      

    </article>
    <!--end article section-->
    <br clear = "all"> <!--clear all formatting-->

    <div class="footer">
        <?php include 'footer.html';?>
    </div>
</body>
<!--End body section-->

</html>
<!--end html here-->
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the sending and not the receiving? An invalid from address is the sort of thing I'd expect a spam filter to complain about bitterly. Have you checked the logs of your outgoing mail server?

Comment: Note that using the sender email in the From address is likely to cause you problems when interacting with SPF, DKIM, and DMARC.

Comment: *regardless of whether their contact information is valid* Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340